# Is there a best practice for migrating Concrete5 sites using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, web-deployment, concrete5

Is there a best practice for migrating Concrete5 sites using MySQL? MySQL database can be finicky and not liked to be just copied from server to server. How are Concrete5 developers handling the develop locally - deploy remotely approach?

Comment: Don't just copy the MySQL files, as this can cause problems with differing server versions - do an export with `mysql_dump` and reimport using `mysql`.

Comment: Will the dump from the (possibly changed) development database mess up the live database when imported there?

Comment: In the sense it will replace it, yes. The simple solution is to take your live site down (either stop the web server, or some software like Wordpress has an "under maintenance" mode). Then rename the existing database to `whatever_name_old`, and then import the new one into `whatever_name`. If the site is critical, then you can script this process so you only have a a minute of downtime, but whilst you are learning, it is good to do it manually (and slowly).

Comment: I don't like MySQL for just these reasons. :( When I found concrete5, I was hoping it might use MongoDB or something that made it easier to just copy over the live database. WordPress has a nice database syncing plugin that they do not, unfortunately, have plans to make into a stand-alone tool that could be used with MySQL in general.

Comment: All relational databases have this issue, though there are probably tools you can use to "hot sync" one database to another. This would determine the differences between two versions and then issue INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE to bring the live one up to speed with development. Or, the low-tech solution is to record all the changes you've made to dev, and play them back in a "change script" on your test and live servers. I do the latter, and that works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are step by step guide, so follow this link: http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/installation/moving_a_site

Note: Make sure that files are correctly under site preferences `Your site's config/site.php will have a constant DIRNAME_APP_UPDATED defined that should match the name of the folder.`

And chmod folder for writing permissions:

```
files/cache/
files/tmp/
updates/
```

Comment: I did read that before I posted. The problem was that it did not seem to address the idea of a subsequent upload after some development revisions. How do you get the new database changes onto the production server without overwriting everything that's there? Or, if you download a snapshot of the database to work with, how do you put it back without overwriting the live database? MySQL seems to add as much development trouble as it solves on the live site.

Comment: It's not trouble from MySQL, developers put full URL in database with source from development with path A. If you put on another server, it will read path A but still not exists. So you need manualy change path A to path B on production server. Then it will read all files in database.

Comment: The URL has been changed to http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/installation/moving-a-site/